# Listing posts from custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a script in place in my wordpress install which shows all the posts which reside under the custom post type 'publicnews'.

The outcome is great and displays all the posts I want to be displayed but the the list is not clickable.

I would like it so each post displayed in the output links to their permalink page.

Essentially what I am looking to do is, display all the posts which sit under the custom post type 'publicnews' in a list outside the loop. The posts which display should be clickable and lead to their full page.

Below is a view of the full code:

```
<!-- Dynamic News Box -->

<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-template panel-color<?=$color?>">
                <div class="panel-body small-text newspagesmall">
                    <h3 class="h3_title">
                        <span class="icon-fleche"></span>
                        <a class="titre_href" href="">
                            NEWS BOX
                        </a>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="scrollablenews_div">
                        <ul>
                            <?php
                            query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'publicnews', 'showposts' => 10 ) );
                            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                            ?>
                            <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
                        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

I hope you can help!

Comment: The code you have shared doesn't have anything to do with displaying the list, only querying for it. You're going to need to share some more of the code, in order for us to help you. Also, it's unclear what exactly should be clickable.

Comment: Essentially what I am looking to do is, display all the posts which sit under the custom post type 'publicnews' in a list outside the loop. The posts which display should be clickable and lead to their full page.

Comment: That's great...but we still need to see your existing code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've made amendments to my initial post.

Comment: The code you've added still doesn't output anything...which is adding to my confusion. In your question, you state: *The outcome is great and displays all the posts I want to be displayed but the the list is not clickable.*. Your code doesn't output any list items...Are you sure this is the correct code?

Comment: Hi Rnevius, I've now included a screenshot of the current output.

Comment: Hi Jake, as @mevius has stated, the code that you've shared doesn't display the custom posts. It just queries for them. Perhaps you should try removing this code and check if *The outcome is great* then.

Comment: Let me try to explain it to you: `<?php
  query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'publicnews', 'showposts' => 10 ) );
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?> 
/* There Should Be Something Here */
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>` <-- look inside your code, where it should have some code outputting your supposed list. It's missing. Please, provide it.

Comment: Would you be able to recomend code which will display a list of the all posts which reside under my post type 'publicnews' as evidently I have got it wrong. To reiterate, I don't want to display the posts body content only the posts names

Comment: Should I assume, then, that `the_post()` is the function that display your list of posts? Because if it is, then you have to manipulate its code, and then we'll need to see its source.

Comment: I simply copied that code from the internet, but it's working as it's pulling up the post titles. I just want to titles to link to the posts themselves

Comment: @AlanMachado , not quite. `the_post()` is a [WordPress function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post) which simply sets up post data. It's not responsible for content output. Which means that **the above code alone cannot be responsible for outputting the list in the screenshot**.

Comment: I've shared the full code view for the page template in question. Thanks for your help

Comment: @rnevius thanks for the info, I'm yet to get to wordpress, I'm still studying Magento. Good to know! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap your title in a proper permalink:

```
<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
</li>
```

This is covered [right in the WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink#Used_as_Link_With_Title_Tag).

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much for your guidance. This insight has helped me! You star.

Comment: You're welcome @Jake . If my answer resolved the problem, please "accept" it by clicking the check mark to the left. Thanks

Comment: Have done this for you :) Whilst we are on the topic, how would one add the post date just below the title?